# On which of the following spaces is every continuous (real-valued) function bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

On which of the following spaces is every continuous (real-valued) function bounded?
  i) $X_1 = (0, 1)$;
  ii) $X_2 = [0,1]$;
  iii) $X_3 = [0, 1)$;
  iv) $X_4 =\{t \in [0, 1] : t \mbox{ irrational}\}$.

(i) is not true: example $f(x)=\frac 1x$ .
(ii) I think this is true as the interval is closed and bounded.
(iii) is not true. Example: $f(x)=\frac 1{1-x}$.
(iv) I think this is true as this is a subset of (ii).

Am I right?

Comment: Keep in mind that case (iv) doesn't actually include the endpoints.

Comment: You’re almost right: (iv) is false for the same reason that (1) or (3) is false. See @Robert’s comment.

Comment: The endpoint argument is not the most important part for (iv) because $x\mapsto \frac1{2x-1}$ is not bounded, either. In other words: $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ would have done as well because $x\mapsto\frac1{x\sqrt2 -1}$ is not bounded.